# Moving ehcache server from one machine to another

Tags: ehcache, terracotta

We have been using ehcache.server.1.0.0.war for almost a year.

This week we moved to new computer. We copied cache and changed ehcache.xml accordingly.

However, the new server is now not starting. It throws the error:

```
             SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
                             at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.warn(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:429)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.deleteIndexIfCorrupt(DiskStore.java:267)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.initialiseFiles(DiskStore.java:210)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.<init>(DiskStore.java:166)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore.create(DiskStore.java:187)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.createDiskStore(Cache.java:1069)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.initialise(Cache.java:941)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:921)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addConfiguredCaches(CacheManager.java:607)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:336)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:276)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:636)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:657)
                             at net.sf.ehcache.server.soap.EhcacheWebServiceEndpoint.<init>(EhcacheWebServiceEndpoint.java:71)
                             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
```

This error happens when you have wrong slf4j version of the jar. Check carefully all jar versions/sizes on your old server and make sure they are the same on a new server.

Also diff. versions of the jars could be in your new app server system classpath that would interfere with your application classpath. You should configure class loading order policy in your deployment descriptor (its specific to the app server vendor you are using)